# Getting TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj while fetching data using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my ajax call

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#blog").focusout(function() {
         alert('Focus out event call');
         alert('hello');
         $.ajax({
             url: '/homes',
             method: 'POST',
             data: 'blog=' + $('#blog').val(),
             success: function(result) {
                 $.each(result, function(key, val) {
                     $("#result").append('<div><label>' + val.description + '</label></div>');
                 });
             },
             error: function() {
                 alert('failure.');
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

I am getting 'TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj ' error in my console

In advance thank you

Comment: are you getting alert..?

Comment: Your code is missing a closing `});`. Is this bad cut-and-paste or the underlying cause?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mention a dataType attribute in your ajax call.It consider text by default.That's why not able to iterate on **result**

```
dataType:'json'
```

Because your **result** should be array or json

Answer (score 1):

the 'result' in success function should be an array

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `data` be an object?

```
data: {
    blog: $('#blog').val()
},
```

Comment: No; http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ states that it can be an object or a string.