# Getting error while using each loop under ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

When i am trying each loop under Ajax call, i am getting error as:

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
```

Below is my Ajax call code

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/counselormanagement/centername",
        data: 'groupId='+valueSelected,
        async: true,
        success: function(arrCenter) {
            $.each(arrCenter, function( intValue, arrValue ) {
                console.log('<option value="' + arrValue['ID'] + '">'+ arrValue['CenterName'] +'</option>');
            });
        }
    });
```

Response which i am getting back from server is :

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 4
        [CenterName] => test2
        [ParentName] => 2
        [Parent] => 3
        [GroupName] => test
        [Type] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 8
        [CenterName] => test21
        [ParentName] => 2
        [Parent] => 3
        [GroupName] => test
        [Type] => 1
    )
 )
```

I am using PHP as backend, whose code is :

```
$arrCenterName   = array();
$objCenterMapper = new Application_Model_CentersMapper();
$arrCenter = $objCenterMapper->seekCenters($_POST['groupId']);
print_r($arrCenter[0]);
die();
```

Comment: Did you try to parse you data as json instead of print_r on php ?

Comment: This code looks fine. can you do a `console.log(arrCenter)`?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(arrCenter)) check. Please attach what type of json you are getting.

Comment: It is a php object. You need a javascript object instead

Comment: What about http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php ?

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460368/getting-typeerror-invalid-in-operand-obj-while-fetching-data-using-ajax

Comment: yes use dataType: "json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to echo out your object using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead:

```
<?php
$arrCenterName   = array();
$objCenterMapper = new Application_Model_CentersMapper();
$arrCenter = $objCenterMapper->seekCenters($_POST['groupId']);
echo json_encode($arrCenter[0]);
die();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode()` in PHP to return response. And your JS code should be like:

PHP:

```
$arrCenterName   = array();
$objCenterMapper = new Application_Model_CentersMapper();
$arrCenter = $objCenterMapper->seekCenters($_POST['groupId']);
echo json_encode($arrCenter[0]);
die();
```

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/counselormanagement/centername",
    data: 'groupId='+valueSelected, 
    dataType: 'json', 
    async: true,
    success: function(arrCenter) {
        $.each(arrCenter, function( intValue, arrValue ) {
            console.log('<option value="' + arrValue.ID + '">'+ arrValue.CenterName +'</option>');
        });
    }
});
```